# Generate a sequence keeping previous element in next element python

Tags: python

I would like to generate a sequence in a list, I know how to do this using a for loop, but if I wanted to generate the list such that the previously generated element was  included in the next element, how would I do this? I am very unsure

i.e generate the list such that its items were:

where x is just a symbol

`[x,(x)*(x+1),(x)*(x+1)*(x+2)]`

rather than `[x,x+1,x+2]`

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: The question isn't terribly clear. I take it `x` isn't always the same thing in your expression?

Comment: @larsmans x is just a symbol

Comment: Never mind, I see it now.

Comment: No I mean a symbol if I multiplied x*x I would get x**2.

Comment: @user1987097 That would be a variable. Symbol is not really a proper term for this context, possibly a *mathematical variable* is what you're after. Programming languages don't know such term, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like to use a generator for this sort of thing.

```
def sequence(x, N):
    i = 0
    result = 1
    while i < N:
        result *= (x + i)
        i += 1
        yield result

>>> list(sequence(5, 10))
[5, 30, 210, 1680, 15120, 151200, 1663200, 19958400, 259459200, 3632428800L]
```

If you have numpy installed, this is faster:

```
np.multiply.accumulate(np.arange(x, x + N))
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to maintain state between the elements, and the list comprehension won't do that for you. A couple of ways to maintain state that come to mind are, a) use a generator, b) use a class EDIT or c) a closure.

Use a generator

```
def product(x, n):
    accumulator = 1
    for i in xrange(n + 1):
        accumulator *= x + i
        yield accumulator

x = 5
print [n for n in product(x, 2)]
# or just list(product(x, 2))
```

Or, use a class to maintain state

```
class Accumulator(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1
        self.count = 0

    def __call__(self, x):
        self.value *= x + self.count
        self.count += 1
        return self.value

a = Accumulator()
x = 5
print [a(x) for _ in xrange(3)]
```

...The benefit of the class approach is that you could use a different value for x each iteration, like:

```
b = Accumulator()
print [b(x) for x in [1, 2, 3]]
>>> [1, 3, 15]
```

EDIT:

Just to be thorough, a closure would work, too:

```
def accumulator():

    # we need a container here because closures keep variables by reference; could have used a list too
    state = {'value': 1, 'count': 0}

    def accumulate(x):
        state['value'] *= x + state['count']
        state['count'] += 1
        return state['value']

    return accumulate

a = accumulator()
print [a(5) for _ in xrange(3)]
```

Comment: lol everyone climbing over each other to write the generator for this ;)

Comment: This is cool, and it reminded me that a numpy ufuncs have an accumulate method that does the job here. (See the edit on my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Deque are used to get a fast access to the elements at the end of the constructing list, as well as a constant append time. pol[-1] means the last element in the queue.

```
from collections import deque
def multCum(f, x, end):
    pol = deque([x])
    for i in range(1, end):
        pol.append(f(pol[-1],(x+i)))
    return list(pol)

def f(x, y):
    return x * y

multCum(f, 1, 3)

[1, 2, 6]
```

Comment: A generator would be a more idiomatic approach than a `deque`. (Besides, lists probably have good enough append time unless you're doing *heavy* modification over the lifetime of the list.)

Answer (score 0):

Use generators with list comprehensions.

```
def reqd(x, n):
    '''x is the number and n is number of elements '''
    yield x

    i = 0
    original = x
    while i < n:
        i += 1
        x *= (original + i)
        yield x

x = 2
listt = [a for a in reqd(x, 10)]
print listt
```

Change the list comprehension in the end to get the list that you want.

Answer (score 0):

More idiomatic hacking using for-comprehensions and a custom operator:

```
def n(a):
    global previous
    previous = a
    return a

[n(previous * (x+i)) for previous in [1] for i in range(0,3)]
```

yields, if x == 1,

```
[1, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Computationally wasteful but gets the job done

```
from operator import mul
z = range(5, 11)
print z                                                                     
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

[reduce(mul, z[:i]) for i in range(1, len(z))]                              
[5, 30, 210, 1680, 15120]
```